# How Can I Install LibreOffice Base?

Tags: installation, package-management, kubuntu, libreoffice

**Useful info:**

- I have tried running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` with no result.
- I am running Kubuntu 11.10 (the updater is far too unreliable to ever be trusted with performing a version upgrade)
- The rest of LibreOffice seems to work fine (apart from an annoying bug where tooltips are shown as black text on black background...)

I have need to use LibreOffice Base to complete a mail merge document. However, I noticed it's not installed. When I go to install it however...

```
rob@hydrogen:~$ sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base
[sudo] password for rob: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-base-core (= 1:3.4.4-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libreoffice-java-common (>= 1:3.4.4~) but it is not going to be installed
                Suggests: libmyodbc but it is not going to be installed or
                          odbc-postgresql but it is not going to be installed or
                          libsqliteodbc but it is not going to be installed or
                          tdsodbc but it is not going to be installed or
                          mdbtools but it is not going to be installed
                Suggests: libreoffice-gcj but it is not installable
                Suggests: libreoffice-report-builder but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm bemused as to which packages it seems to think I have held. As far as I'm aware, Kubuntu doesn't give you the option to hold packages... So, how do I get out of this dependency hell?

Comment: Have you tried Synaptic?

Comment: Yes. Synaptic recommends the removal of every other component of LibreOffice, along with a wide array of other packages.

Answer (score 8):

To install LibreOffice Base, use Ubuntu Software Center. It works without problems. (If Ubuntu Software Center isn't installed, use Synaptic or Muon to get it.)

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to install LibreOffice manually on ubuntu. There are deb tgz packages ([x86_64](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86_64) or [x86](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/?type=deb-x86)). To install them, just unpack tham and issue `dpkg -i *.deb` in the DEBS subdirectoy (the install packages have another subdirectoy, "desktop-integration" - take care to install the `deb` from there, too).

Comment: I'll give this a try. However, the whole point of the repositories is to avoid having to download individual deb files to install, surely?